# How can I merge these many csv files (around 130,000) using PySpark into one large dataset efficiently?

Tags: python, apache-spark, memory, pyspark, bigdata

I posted this question earlier and got some advice to use PySpark instead.

[How can I merge this large dataset into one large dataframe efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60259271/how-can-i-merge-this-large-dataset-into-one-large-dataframe-efficiently)

The following zip file (https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories/32263/downloaddata/INTRNTL_csv_2.zip) contains a folder called data with around 130,000 of csv files. I want to merge all of them into one single dataframe. I have 16gb of RAM and I keep running out of RAM when I hit the first few hundred files. The files' total size is only about 300-400 mb of data.

If you open up any of the csv files, you can see that they all have the same format, the first column is for dates, and the second column is for the data series.

So now instead I am using PySpark, however I have no idea what is the most efficient way to connect all the files, with pandas dataframes I would just concat the list of individual frames like this because I want them to merge on the dates:

```
bigframe = pd.concat(listofframes,join='outer', axis=0)
```

But like I mentioned, this method doesn't work as I run out of RAM really fast.

What would be the best way to do something similar using PySpark?

So far I have this, (by the way the filelist below is just a list of the files which I want to pull out, you can ignore that)

```
import os

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('spark-dataframe-demo').getOrCreate()
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

listdf = []

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("/kaggle/input/filelist/"):
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(subdir,file)
        print(file)
        filelist = pd.read_excel("/kaggle/input/filelist/" + file)

        for row in filelist.File.items():
            df = spark.read.csv(f"/kaggle/input/master/{file[:-5]}/{file[:-5]}/data/" + row[1], inferSchema = True, header = True)
            df = df.select(col("DATE").alias("DATE"),col("VALUE").alias(row[1][:-4]))
            df.show(3)
            listdf.append(df)
```

I stop the code after it appends like 10 frames,
But when I try the code below, it just has one column of data, it doesn't merge properly.

```
bigframe = reduce(DataFrame.join(listdf, ['DATE'], how='full'))
```

But I am only left with 2 columns of data, the date and the first item in the list of spark frames.

How do I merge everything into one frame properly? I want the Dates to be the thing index that the other columns merge on. Meaning if one frame has:

```
Date        TimeSeries1
1 Jan 2012  12345
2 Jan 2012  23456
```

and the other has

```
Date        TimeSeries2
1 Jan 2012  5678
3 Jan 2012  8910
```

I want the final product to be

```
Date        TimeSeries1 TimeSeries2
1 Jan 2012  12345       5678
2 Jan 2012  23456
3 Jan 2012              8910
```

Also, to identify the columns, the names have to be changed to the name of the file.

Comment: So, would you like a dataframe with shape nx130.001? (number of total rows x number of files + date columns)? I'll try to help you when I arrive at home, it doesn't seem very dificult

Comment: Yes, correct. Thanks!

Comment: also the column names need to be the name of the file. It's pretty easy to do in pandas but I have no idea how to do it in pyspark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a lot of stuff happening here, but if I can distill this to the need to merge data from 130k CSV files into one single DF, and capture the name for each file, you can do it like this.

```
from  pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

customSchema = StructType([ \
StructField("asset_id", StringType(), True), \
StructField("price_date", StringType(), True), \
etc., 
StructField("close_price", StringType(), True), \
StructField("filename", StringType(), True)])

fullpath = 'mnt/INTRNTL_csv_2/data/??/*.csv'

df = spark.read.format("csv") \
   .option("header", "false") \
   .option("sep","|") \
   .schema(customSchema) \
   .load(fullPath) \
   .withColumn("filename", input_file_name())
```

Notice: The very first line of code and the very last line of code are used to get the file names.  Also, pay attention to the wildcards; the '?' is for one single character (either a letter or a number) and the '*' is for any number of characters (any combination of letters and numbers).

Comment: hi, I'm really new to Pyspark, could you take a look at this error and tell me what's wrong? I added from pyspark import SparkContext sc = SparkContext(), and I removed the etc., line, but I get this error ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=pyspark-shell, master=local[*]) created by __init__ at <ipython-input-6-45c664737be5>:2

Comment: Are you running multiple instances of Spark?  Try use sc.stop() before you were trying to create another SparkContext.  Stop everything and start at the beginning.  Modify the code that I posted, to suit your specific needs, and run it.  It should work fine.  It worked fine for me.

Comment: I ran the code exactly as you put it when I ran it it said there was no instance of sc

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on.  It worked fine for me, over the course of the past 7-8 months.

Comment: Even the etc part? That was a comment or part of the code?

Comment: In this line:  StructField("asset_id", StringType(), True), \
the variable named "asset_id" is my specific field name; the first field in my dataset.  You have to pop in your specific field name.  Do that for each field in your dataset.  If your default schema works totally fine, you don't need to use a custom schema.  Make sense?

Comment: I start a new notebook with the code exactly as you gave me, it says sc is not defined. I can see you put the variable sc into the SQLContext method, did you define it before this code?

Comment: hey okay, so i had to add a few lines to get the code working on my machine. but i get columns of null entries and the last column is just a filepath, that's not what I had in mind, what i meant was each file would create a new column in the dataframe. right now its just appending filepaths into one column

Comment: That's what it is supposed to do.  Get rid of the very last line of code if you don't want to append file paths & file names.  I can't imagine a scenario where 'each file would create a new column in the dataframe'.  That makes no sense at all.  I think it's time to start a new question at this point.

Comment: ive been saying that from the start of my question, if you could take a look at it again, ive been saying that each file creates a new column, in pandas it would be an full outer join, see the last part of my question i show an example of how the columns append

Answer (score 2):

spark can read data from multiple files by default if they contain the same schema.

To process each timeseries separately, you can group by the dataframe by filename and use a pandas udf to process each group.

```
import glob as g
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

@F.pandas_udf("date Date, value DECIMAL(38,4)", F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def transform(pdf):
  # pdf will be a pandas datafrmme for each timeseries
  # apply timeseries computations here and return a new dataframe
  # with aggregated values
  return pdf

paths = g.glob("./INTRNTL_csv_2/data/**/*.csv", recursive=True)

df = spark.read.csv(paths, header=False, schema="date DATE, value DECIMAL(38,4)")


res = df.withColumn('name', F.input_file_name())
res = res.groupBy('name').apply(transform)
res.show()
```

Comment: then how do you merge them all ?

Comment: the result is a single merged dataframe containing all the data from all files

Comment: it goes /data/A/A/A/aaaaa.csv data/A/A/B/aaaab.csv or it might be data /A/aaa.csv, will that cover everything? also the column names would all be VALUE right?

Comment: yes, `**/*.csv` means - `**` for  parse the tree recursivly and load all files with `*.csv` extension

Comment: saw, the files have headers, you need to pass an option to omit them.. changed the answer

Comment: it seems it doesnt join the data column wise, i think its appending row wise

Comment: that would be a very inconvenient method for further processing. You can run group_by on the data column and collect all the values for that particular date as list

Comment: run the snippet on the data, apparently spark cannot deal with recursive globs, but you can pass an array of paths. Python glob module can deal with recursive  wildcards. Also some values were to big for double datatype. changed to `decimal` with precision of 38 (total digits) and scale of 4 (digits after comma)

Comment: ok so it looks like theres only 2 columns and in the second column its just a list of all the data, what i meant was Date | AAA | AAB | AAC not Date | Values. Is that possible?

Comment: Then you would really need to write custom code like in your example. Why do you want to create individually named columns with the same name as folder path? Do those folder letter mean anything? I looks to me, like this is just a file split pattern. 
WIth the snippet form the  answer, you get all the values for a particular date in a single row
If you join evetything into a dataframe with a date column and n named valued colums , how dou you want to access the data, without knowing those names?

If you just want to access the whole row, you still can , if the values is an array

Comment: each file is a different time series

Comment: you could grouby by input_file_name() then and try to use a pandas udf on each group

Comment: another question. Are you sure you want to join all csv in only one dataframe? I've read "README" file and it seems that the .csv files contain different type of values, some percentages, some ints, some... with a different meaning...

Comment: yeah i realise but i wanna do it that way

Comment: Also, there is a file in the main folder called README_SERIES_ID_SORT, which is a csv of all the directories and series names. It can be easily separated into columns using excel. It can be used to cycle through every single file in the set.