# Using PySpark to efficiently combine many small csv files (130,000 with 2 columns in each) into one large frame

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, memory, pyspark

This is another follow up to an earlier question I posted [How can I merge these many csv files (around 130,000) using PySpark into one large dataset efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60261615/how-can-i-merge-these-many-csv-files-around-130-000-using-pyspark-into-one-lar)

I have the following dataset https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories/32263/downloaddata/INTRNTL_csv_2.zip

In it, there's a list of files (around 130,000). In the main directory with their sub-directories listed, so in there the first cell might be A/AAAAA, and the file would be located at /data/A/AAAAA.csv

The files are all with a similar format, the first column is called DATE and the second column is a series which are all named VALUE. So first of all, **the VALUE column name needs to be renamed to the file name in each csv file**. Second, the frames need to be full outer joined with each other with the DATE as the main index. Third, I want to save the file and be able to load and manipulate it. The file should be around N rows (number of dates) X 130,001 roughly.

I am trying to full outer join all the files into a single dataframe, I previously tried pandas but ran out of memory when trying to concat the list of files and someone recommended that I try to use PySpark instead.

In a previous post I was told that I could do this:

```
df = spark.read.csv("/kaggle/input/bf-csv-2/BF_csv_2/data/**/*.csv", "date DATE, value DOUBLE")
```

But all the columns are named value and the frame just becomes two columns, the first column is DATE and second column is VALUE, it loads quite fast, around 38 seconds and around 3.8 million values by 2 columns, so I know that it's not doing the full outer join, it's appending the files row wise.

So I tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import os

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('spark-dataframe-demo').getOrCreate()
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import *

filelist = pd.read_excel("/kaggle/input/list/BF_csv_2.xlsx") #list of filenames

firstname = min(filelist.File)
length = len(filelist.File)

dff = spark.read.csv(f"/kaggle/input/bf-csv-2/BF_csv_2/data/" + firstname, inferSchema = True, header = True).withColumnRenamed("VALUE",firstname) #read file and changes name of column to filename

for row in filelist.File.items():
    if row == firstname:
        continue

    print (row[1],length,end='', flush=True)
    df = spark.read.csv(f"/kaggle/input/bf-csv-2/BF_csv_2/data/" + row[1], inferSchema = True, header = True).withColumnRenamed("VALUE",row[1][:-4])
    #df = df.select(col("DATE").alias("DATE"),col("VALUE").alias(row[1][:-4]))

    dff = dff.join(df, ['DATE'], how='full')

    length -= 1

dff.write.save('/kaggle/working/whatever', format='parquet', mode='overwrite')
```

So to test it, I try to load the the df.show() function after 3 columns are merged and it's quite fast. But, when I try around 25 columns, it takes around 2 minutes. When I try 500 columns it's next to impossible.

I don't think I'm doing it right. The formatting and everything is correct. But why is it taking so long? How can I use PySpark properly? Are there any better libraries to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark doesn't do anything magical compared to other software. The strength of spark is parallel processing. Most of the times that means you can use multiple machines to do the work. If you are running spark locally you may have the same issues you did when using pandas.

That being said, there might be a way for you to run it locally using Spark because it can spill to disk under certain conditions and does not need to have everything in memory.

I'm not verse in PySpark, but the approach I'd take is:

1. load all the files using like you did `/kaggle/input/bf-csv-2/BF_csv_2/data/**/*.csv`
2. Use the function `from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name` that allows you to get the path for each record in your `DF` (`df.select("date", "value", input_file_name().as("filename"))` or similar)
3. Parse the path into a format that I'd like to have as a column (eg. extract filename)
4. the schema should look like `date, value, filename` at this step
5. use the PySpark equivalent of `df.groupBy("date").pivot("filename").agg(first("value"))`. Note: I used `first()` because I think you have 1 or 0 records possible
6. Also try: setting the number of partitions to be equal to number of dates you got
7. If you want output as a single file, do not forget to `repartition(1)` before `df.write`. This step might be problematic depending on data size. You do not need to do this if you plan to keep using Spark for your work as you could load the data using the same approach as in step 1 (`/new_result_data/*.csv`)